# Should I submit notice?

Tags: resignation

So I work for a security company in a specific building.  I really like the site.  The building manager is no longer happy with my company so they are changing companies but want to keep me and my supervisor.  I interview for my job on Thursday and am curious if I should submit a resignation letter.

Comment: Well, if you don’t officially have a job yet, then why resign? It’s always up in the air until something solid is offered.

Answer (score 8):

The question is not if you should submit it, the question is when. You have, at the moment, no guarantees that you will be picked up by the new company. Don't submit anything until you have a firm job with the new company.